# Write Variable Length Arrays to a Database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I process a list of articles, each of which contains variable amount of tags. How can I store list of tags as array in column if I don't know how many tags will I have with later updates? First time I can insert lists of tags with same length just by filling them by `None`, but what if with new update I'll get more longer lists of tags?

today's list of tags:

```
[tag1, tag2]
[tag1, tag2, tag3]
```

ok, got it! max length is 3, make equal length:

```
[tag1, tag2, None]
[tag1, tag2, tag3]
```

tomorrow's list of tags:

```
[tag1, tag2]
[tag1, tag2, tag3]
[tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4]
```

ok, got it! my max length is 3:

```
[tag1, tag2, None]
[tag1, tag2, tag3]
[tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4] <- here is problem
```

maybe someone knows better solution for this case?

update:

```
for tags in tags_list:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tags VALUES (%s)""", (tags,))
```

Comment: The max length of a Postgres array isn't limited (even if you define it like that). So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name question is how can I store the arrays with variable length

Comment: @Antosha - you don't keep each tag in separate column - right?..

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is no fixed length for an array in Postgres. If you want to add a new element, just add it

Comment: @VaoTsun even if I will store then in columns, how many columns should I have?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension. A mismatch causes an error.

Comment: your sample arrays are not multidimensional. in that case I'd maybe consider using jsonb

Comment: Your example is not a multidimensional array. And I don't see any reason for storing a _list_ of tags in a multidimensional array.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right, I have list of lists. maybe you know how to write lists in loop?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see update, please. feel like I have to use `executemany` method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that arrays have a fixed length in Postgres - but they don't:

```
create table antosha (article_id integer primary key, tags text[]);
insert into antosha (article_id, tags)
values 
  (1, array['sql', 'dbms']),
  (2, array['java', 'jdbc']);
```

If you want to add tag, just append them:

```
-- append a single tag
update antosha
  set tags = tags || 'postgresql'
where id = 1;

-- append multiple tags
update antosha
  set tags = tags || array['kotlin', 'python']
where id = 2;
```

Or replace the tags completely:

```
update antosha
  set tags = array['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
where id = 1;
```

Or remove a single element:

```
update antosha
  set tags = array_remove(tags, 'two')
where id = 1;
```

Or replace a single element:

```
update antosha
  set tags = array_replace(tags, 'one', '001')
where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

just store as is:

```
t=# create table a (c text[]);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into a values(array['a']),(array['a','b']),(array['a','b','2']);
INSERT 0 3
t=# select * from a;
    c
---------
 {a}
 {a,b}
 {a,b,2}
(3 rows)
```